# Transform to Linq (overlap validations)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, overlap, gaps-in-data

I Have a Tuple list and I want to find overlaps:

```
static bool Overlap(params Tuple<int, int>[] ranges) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 < ranges.Length) {
            if (!(ranges[i].Item1 < ranges[i].Item2 
                  && ranges[i + 1].Item1 > ranges[i].Item2)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I transform this into linq?
How can I find if exists gaps with linq, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the power of ReSharper i present to you:

```
return ranges.Where((t, i) => i + 1 < ranges.Length 
                     && !(t.Item1 < t.Item2 && ranges[i + 1].Item1 > t.Item2)).Any();
```

---

To find out if gaps exist or not you need to check whether the next elements start value is above your current elements end value. So just change `>` to `<=`.

```
return ranges.Where((t, i) => i + 1 < ranges.Length 
                     && !(t.Item1 < t.Item2 && ranges[i + 1].Item1 <= t.Item2)).Any();
```

Comment: @BrunoLeitão Do you want to find all gaps or do you want to know if there are any gaps?

Comment: i want to find if exists gaps or overlaps

Answer (score 1):

```
return ranges
    .Zip(ranges.Skip(1), (t1, t2) => new { T1 = t1, T2 = t2 })
    .Any(p => !(p.T1.Item1 < p.T1.Item2 && p.T2.Item1 > p.T1.Item2))
```

Comment: And if i want to find gaps?

Comment: @user2252371 - If you mean you want to know if there are any adjacent elements which don't overlap, then just invert the condition given to `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use [.Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) here as it doesn't include an overload that allows access to an index.

```
static bool Overlap(params Tuple<int, int>[] ranges) {
    return ranges
        .Where((range, i) =>
            i < ranges.Length && 
            !(range.Item1 < range.Item2 && 
              ranges[i + 1].Item1 > range.Item2)
        .Any();
}
```